# How to check that app is ever installed on device by packagename

Tags: android, installation

i am trying to check any packagename that is installed ever in device from my app.
How can i do that.

E.g. in my app i want to check "com.exampkle.com" ever install in device.

Please help me.
Sorry for off topic question but it was very important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid the Android system can't remember which app it used to installed. When the app removed ,Android will delete all information about this app. but you mention the apps were installed by your app , so you can record the app and sync it to the cloud .

Comment: Then how some earn money type app know install is unique or not like fyber offer,tapjoy etc.

Comment: i want to check by my app. i m not want to install from my app

Comment: @GohilSoftware When you use tapjoy or other ads apps , you should get a key_id for your own app from the tapjoy. so through the id , tapjoy would recognize you .